# Stop animation outside the focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a user-friendly multiple select created with [jQuery Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#multiple-select). The height of the container div increases when selecting multiple elements, and if the container div is on **focus** I have set height to auto but if is on **blur** I set it to fixed height.

```
$('.chosen-container-multi').live('focus', function(event) {   
    var select = $('.chosen-container-multi').find(".chosen-choices");
    var curHeight =  select.height();
    var autoHeight = select.height();

    curHeight = select.height();
    autoHeight = select.css('height', 'auto').height();
    select.height(curHeight).stop(true, true).animate({height: autoHeight}, 300);

    event.stopPropagation();
}).live('blur',function(){
    $('.chosen-container-multi').find(".chosen-choices").animate({height: 30}, 300);
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fHABD/7/)

[image]

The problem is that when I click on the items (the div that contains *options*) outside the div container the height animates to 30px and then returns to auto (see the gif image above).
How do I prevent this behavior?

Thank you so much! and sorry for my bad english! :)

Comment: It works fine for me. What browser gives this behavior?

Comment: Google Chrome v30.0, but I also tested on Firefox v24.0 and I get the same problem. Select an option and then try to select again that option (disabled, which has gray text) and you will see.

Comment: Try to select all the options, and then try again to select an option even if it is already selected.

Comment: Now I see what you meant, sorry it took so long. I updated your fiddle and now it only will slide up when the user selects something, or it loses focus on both elements: http://jsfiddle.net/fHABD/8/ I hope this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much! please post your answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the `blur` callback function on the parent of both elements, not on the input element only, since the plugin will create another element after the input field inside the same parent. I've updated your <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fHABD/8/)</kbd>

```
$('.chosen-container-multi').live('focus', function (event) {
    var select = $('.chosen-container-multi').find(".chosen-choices");
    var curHeight = select.height();
    var autoHeight = select.height();

    curHeight = select.height();
    autoHeight = select.css('height', 'auto').height();
    select.height(curHeight).stop(true, true).animate({
        height: autoHeight
    }, 300);

    event.stopPropagation();
});

// !! Selector of the parent
$('.chosen-select').live('blur', function () {
    $('.chosen-container-multi').find(".chosen-choices").animate({
        height: 30
    }, 300);
});
```